# get html nextSibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

This Meteor client code tries to get 2 values.
(1)The value in the `this.label` of `<span class="radio-label">{{this.label}}</span>` line.
(2)The value in `{{this.result}}` in the line `<input type="radio" name="rbtn" value={{this.result}}>`
And that needs to happen when I click on either the `input` or on the `span` elements.  How can that be done? thx

```
Template.results.events({
  'click .twin-item': (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (event.target.tagName === 'SPAN') {
      console.log(event.target.innerHTML);
    } else if (event.target.tagName === 'INPUT') {
      console.log(event.target.value);
    }
  }
});


<template name="results">
 <p id="result" data-id={{_id}}>{{{display.name}}} <br>
{{display.address}} <br>
<span id="category">{{display.result}}</span></p> <br>
  <div class="twin-group js-radioGroup" data-id={{_id}}>
    <ul class="upShift">
      {{#each display.deciders}}
        <li>
          <label class="twin-item">
            <input type="radio" name="rbtn" value={{this.result}}>
            <span class="radio-label">{{this.label}}</span>
          </label>
        </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: `twin-group` is referring to the `div` element. So your event gets fired when you click on that `div`. `event.target` refers to that div and that means `event.target.tagName` will always give div. You should add the twin-group class to the span and input field

Comment: @Femi Oladeji  He is using `twin-item` in the click handler

Comment: Oh true, thanks @NikolayErmakov

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are trying to extract something from the DOM that you originally put there in your template you are probably doing it wrong.

You can nest another template inside your `{{#each}}` loop then in the event of that nested template handler the value of `this` will be the current data context so you can do:

html:

```
<template name="results">
<p id="result" data-id={{_id}}>{{{display.name}}} <br>
{{display.address}} <br>
<span id="category">{{display.result}}</span></p> <br>
  <div class="twin-group js-radioGroup" data-id={{_id}}>
    <ul class="upShift">
      {{#each display.deciders}}
        {{> inner}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<template name="inner">
<li>
  <label class="twin-item">
    <input type="radio" name="rbtn" value={{result}}>
    <span class="radio-label">{{label}}</span>
  </label>
</li>
</template>
```

Also it can be simpler to attach an event to each control rather than trying to figure out which control the event came from:

js:

```
Template.inner.events({
  'click input'(event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log(this.result);
  },
  'click span'(event) =>{
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log(this.label);  
  }
});
```

Comment: This solution did not work for me. Clicking on the `span` gave "undefined" and clicking on the radio button gave "<p id="result>~</p>"" I will update the question code to show this `p` tag.

Comment: This updated solution did not work. Clicking on the `span` gave "undefined" on one line and "<p id="result>~</p>"" on the new line. Clicking on the radio button gave "<p id="result>~</p>"", which is the first `p` element under the "result" Template.

Comment: `this` in an event handler should be the data context of the template. It sounds like in your case its not which means something else is wrong. Is your event handler wrapped in some other code? (Like a tracker autorun?)

Comment: The event handler is exactly as you supplied it and not wrapped in any other code.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me. but I am hoping this is a better solution.
By adding different class to the `input` and the `span` elements and play around with the event handler.

```
Template.results.events({
  'click .radio-label': (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    let option = event.target.innerHTML;
    let btn = event.target.parentElement.children[0];
    let res = btn.getAttribute('value');
    btn.checked = true;
    console.log(option + ' ' + res);
  },
  'click .radio-btn': (event) => {
    let res = event.target.parentElement.children[0].getAttribute('value');
    let option = event.target.parentElement.children[1].innerHTML;
    console.log(option + ' ' + res);
  }
});
```

```html
<template name="results">
  <p id="result" data-id={{_id}}>{{{display.name}}} <br>
    {{display.address}} <br>
    <span id="category">{{display.result}}</span></p>

  <div class="twin-group js-radioGroup">
    <ul class="upShift">
      {{#each display.deciders}}
        <li>
          <label class="twin-item">
            <input class="radio-btn" type="radio" name="rbtn" value={{this.result}}>
            <span class="radio-label">{{this.label}}</span>
          </label>
        </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```